# Access Docker container's HTTP port via Tor hidden service

Tags: tor

I have a docker container which I'm using as my personal task manager. I have exposed the HTTP port of the docker container to port 8080 of my host machine (Ubuntu). While I'm on my local network, I can access my docker container like this: `http://ip-of-my-ubuntu-host-machine:8080`

Now, I want to be able to access my docker container also when I'm not at home and I don't have an public IP address assigned to me specifically. So, I would like to use Tor Hidden Service to be able to access my container from outside (yes, I'm comfortable using Tor for this purpose).

Can anyone, please, give me a guide on how to approach this? The problem is, that I do not want to set up the `HiddenServiceDir` in `torrc` file since I do not want to host anything directly on my Tor installation on my host machine, but rather use it as a proxy to forward the traffic to my docker container which then will serve the web page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have managed to get it up and running correctly.
Here's what I've done:

1. Add the following to the /etc/tor/torrc file:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/my_hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

2. Restart Tor with `sudo systemctl restart tor`
3. Your .onion address is located at `/var/lib/tor/my_hidden_server/hostname` (you can view it by performing `cat /var/lib/tor/my_hidden_server/hostname`